# Why i don't have "Graph Shader" parameter in VFX editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I was watching a tutorial on how to make a special effect, I managed to make the shaders but when I got to the special effects I could not find the "Graph Shader" parameter in the output panel

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Goto `Edit > Preferences > Visual effects` and check the `Experimental Operators/Blocks` field

[image: Screenshot of VFX graph settings]